# Fetching the last occurence in byte array without looping

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I've been trying to fetch the last occurrence of '\n' from a byte array of fixed size(that can be defined by me), i.e '\' & 'n' occur together.

What I tried doing is

- Looping the byte array from (0 to size) and (size to 0), but I need to avoid for loops since I will be processing a lot of arrays.
- Convert the byte to char and processing on that

Is there a more better solution than this? I'm a beginner to data structures and doing this in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the general case there is no other way to find the last occurrence but to iterate through the array. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you *must* avoid loops, you could do it by recursion (i.e. if you know the array is of length `i`, consider the sub-arrays between `0..i/2` and `(i/2+1)..i`, and keep subdividing until you've got an array of length 1, and then check if that is a newline character` - but I'd question why you need to avoid loops.

Comment: @Andy Turner I think you'd find that performs way worse than simply iterating.

Comment: @JohnSensebe I agree. The question asks if you can do it without looping; the answer is yes, if you use recursion. Note I say "I'd question why you need to avoid loops".

Comment: @Andy Turner Techincally, the question is "Is there a more better solution than this?" ;-)

Comment: Looping takes time to reach to '\n' character so its degrade the performance.I'm trying to find-out specific pattern from the byte array !!

Comment: "Looping the byte array from (0 to size) and (size to 0)" why in both directions? If you are looking for the last occurrence, just go from `size-1` to `0`, and stop as soon as you have found a `\n`.

Comment: BTW - you are mixing up types - `'\n'` is a `char`, but you say you have a `byte` array. Which is it?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes. The '\' and 'n' are different char, each a byte

Comment: @NeelShah so are you saying that you are actually looking for `\ ` followed by `n` (in some character encoding) as two separate bytes? That's not what `\n` means - it is the newline character literal.

Comment: @AndyTurner Exactly. That's what I'm doing. I've edited the question

Comment: "but I need to avoid for loops since I will be processing a lot of arrays." This statement makes no sense.

Comment: First question: Is the time you spend looking for this last occurrence really a performance bottleneck? If no, then stop worrying about it. Or, if you want to eliminate the explicit loop, convert it to a string and call `LastIndexOf`("\\n")`. You can't avoid a loop here. If you really must optimize, then do as has been suggested: start scanning backwards from the end, looking for `n` followed by `\`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can't find something unless one looks. You have to examine the array to find specific bytes within it. There is no getting around that. Remember that you can `break` out of the loop if you start from the tail, because the first "\\n" you find will be the last occurrence in the array.

Since you've edited your question, let me add this. You can loop two-by-two, and if the byte in question is either '\\' or 'n', then you can check the next byte or the previous byte for the other character. That might be more efficient.